# Dropdown list with jquery validation on change add class

Tags: jquery, validation

I have been asked to add some validation to a drop down list when it changes.

I was going to simply add a class on change to the drop down list, however I am afraid I can't quite work it out, so any help really would be very much appreciated.

Below is my html

```
<select class="dropdownlist">
    <option class="1">1</option>
    <option class="2">2</option>
    <option class="3">3</option>
    <option class="4">4</option>
 </select>
```

and here is my jquery

```
 $('.dropdownlist').change(function(){
    $(this).find('option:selected').addClass("testclass") );
 });
```

I am pretty new to jQuery so if the mistake is a simple one then I apologize.

Cheers

Cameron

Comment: What do you mean validation? What do you need to validate?

Comment: `select` elements are pretty constrained anyway, I don't know why you would want to validate them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying exactly but you have an extra ")" in `addClass("testclass") );`

Comment: is not clear at all what your goal is

Answer (score 2):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/dgVL9/

Issue was extra `)`

```
 $(this).find('option:selected').addClass("testclass") );

                                                       ^--------- this is issue
```

Hope this not the validation plugin because I can not see validate plugin reference I reckon you just meant on change event.
hope it fits the cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$('.dropdownlist').change(function() {
    $(this).find('option:selected').addClass("testclass");
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').prop('class'))
});​
```

Comment: very much appreciated, this is exactly what I wanted. CHEERS